# JNA using 32 bit dll on Win7 64 bit machine

Tags: java, dll, jna

I have been working in Java for past 8 months. Currently I am using JNA to load a third party DLL and it works fine on 32bit WinXP and 32bit Win7 machines.

On a 64bit Win7 machine, this third party dll is present under **C:\Program Files(x86)**, I assume this means its a 32 bit DLL. So, here is the configuration I used so far,

**Win7 machine    - 64 bit,
Third party dll - 32 bit (as per above mentioned assumption),
JRE             - tried with both 32bit and 64bit**

But I get the following - "**error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Wrapper': The specified module could not be found."**

Please let me know if JNA supports loading a 32bit DLL, using a 32 bit JRE on a 64bit machine. Also, if this 32bit DLL has dependencies on other 32 & 64 bit DLLs would JNA still support it.

I am going to use procexp to find out if I am missing any dependencies. I will update this post accordingly.

**Please provide your expert advise. Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JNA does support loading 32 bit DLLs on a 64bit machine. But we need a 32 bit JVM to do this.
I was using Platform.is64Bit() to determine the path of the DLL. I learnt that this method returns the configuration of the JVM and not the OS.

So, in my case when I was using 32bit VM on 64bit machine, the path to the DLL was wrong.

Comment: Is it possibile to load a 32bit dll on a 64bit jre?

Comment: Is it possible to have booth 32 and 64 bit jre installed on a machine? Mainly on Linux

Comment: Yes, you are able to have both 32 and 64 bit JREs on a machine at the same time.  I've done so on Linux, Windows, and Solaris.